# set multiple costs and qty for products

Tags: product, quantity

I have been trying to find something out there that would let me tie more then one cost and qty for each wholesaler I have for a product.  Really what I need is to not just add a new cost and qty tie to a product over what is in the product model but that I'd need to be able to overwrite the qty to have the output be the total of all the tied entries to that product.  My first thought was to just make a table where it had a list of the supplier with their cost and qty that ties to a product.  Not totally clear where to start on that, but then I figured someone has made this already.  Anyone have an idea how to start it or a stub or module already sort of close to what I'm asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the multi-warehouse problem where you have different inventories in different warehouses. 
For your purposes, each vendor/supplier would be a "warehouse" with the total qty showing up in the product total.

There are 3-4 warehouse extensions that I think could accomplish this for you. Some will allow you to set up rules for which inventory is used when an order is placed or allow the customer to select. If these are dropship then there are extensions for that as well. (I don't work for any of these companies: ) In no particular order I have looked at [InnoExts](http://innoexts.com/promotions/warehouse-2/)  [EmbeddedERP](http://www.boostmyshop.com/english/extension-logistique.html)  [Aitoc](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_multi_location_inventory.html) some others not listed.

My experience is that I have been  looking for a multi-warehouse solution that allow shipping from that location and I see the connection / similarity with your problem as stated.

Comment: yeah, they do drop ship but that is not really needed as it's not magneto as of yet that places the order, we do it by hand so having dropship extras are only pluses.  Problem is those are paid(and expensive-ish) modules and I would need to hack them up so that it reads right.  That is why I was looking for something in the free realm that could do it or be a stub I could edit and make things like labels and directions fit.  The from scratch way I just can't seem to think of where to start.  tk for the help

Comment: ok, I think http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dropshipper-7085.html may be close but yes I think this approach will give the best starting point.

Comment: yes those warehouse extensions are a bit pricy but the more I look at maintaining multiple qty and cost per sku for a warehouse i pause. Are you going to run into the need to have different shipping costs depending on supplier? How many suppliers? 2 or 200?    Update this question with what you find...

Comment: all I need is for it to qty cost and alternate sku as far as it really goes and I have 3-5 wholesalers.  so it doesn't have to be beefy.  Since we do flat rate usps for most all orders it's not an issue for the shipping too.  would be nice to have the extra stuff for sure.. but just to costly.

Comment: did you have any success in looking at multi warehouse / dropshipping for a starting point?

Comment: I am having to write my own, but I'm taking queues from the dropshipping module.  After exploring out the solution, it was very incomplete and odd.  It let you tie products to a dropshipper, yea.. it would let you change the price and stock amount under the dropshipper, yips... but then when you did any changes to another dropshipper, those products would reflect the changes from the other, as it's changing the product it's self.  Not good when each dropshipper has different price points to qty's.  So I have to write a new module

Comment: Price will be more complex i think. stock qty tables have a stock_id that may be used for several qtys for the same product. it's not built out at all but i'm looking closely at that.

Comment: the thought was that I would just use the logic of the custom price module that is out there, and set the price on display by a rule, like lowst price or lowset cost.. then it should be straight forward on that.. drop in on the orders and invoices to pull from the right one and all should be good..

Comment: just fyi I have started mine, https://github.com/jeremyBass/dropshippers/ if you have anything to contribute I'd bet it can meet your needs as well.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you want to set up multiple simple products with differing qty, wholesaler/vendor and pricing/cost attributes in the backend, relating them for the frontend as a singular configurable product.

When a customer chooses a product feature that defines it to be sold from a particular vendor it will deduct the qty from that vendor alone.

Comment: the issue is there is near 50,000 products.  I thought about that but it seems with the lead boots that magento tends to walk in, all the tricks to gain speed would be shoot if I had 3-4 version of a product, plus then I can't have real configurable product if those are of these sodo configurable products.. ie I'd have some monster configurable products with lets say a color variation where each one of those had 3-4 vendor variations.  Or am I off?  just seems like I would be making lead weights for the site doing it that way?